# Многомерное нормальное распределение

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, boost, генерация-случайных-данных

В стандартной библиотеке есть инструменты для генерации значений из одномерного нормального распределения (`std::normal_distribution`). Есть ли подобное для многомерного нормального распределения? Если нет, то есть ли в бусте?

Comment: По идее его можно получить из одномерного, нет?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, что вам надо - вектор (x_i) - так он создается просто как набор независимых случайных нормально распределенных величин (см. [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Немного тяжелее, если они должны быть зависимы - но и тут такое распределение строится на основании одномерного. Ничего специально многомерного, как я понимаю, и не нужно :)

Comment: @Harry у меня есть m-вектор мат. ожиданий и m-m ковариационная матрица. Надо семплить m-вектора из МНР с этими параметрами. Если бы матрица была диагональная, то можно было бы просто m раз применить одномерное и получить нужный вектор, но в общем случае это неверно

Comment: @user7860670 как?

Comment: Размерность векторов большая? Возможно ли решить задачу о собственных векторах для матрицы ковариаций, или она слишком большая?

Comment: @Chorkov небольшая, до 10 точно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Математический алгоритм:

1. Перейти в новуй систему координат (x->y), сдвинув начало координат, в точку математического ожидания. Пепесчитать матрицу ковариаций. `Ay[i,j]=Ax[i,j]-m[i]*m[j]`
2. Просверим что матрица Ay не диагональная.
3. Найдем собственные вектора матрицы Ay `E=EigenVectors(Ay)`.
4. Перейдем в новую систему координат (вращение), так чтобы оси новой систему соотвесвовали собственным векторам (y->z). `Az = E * Ay * E^-1`. В этой системе координат, матрица Az должна быть диагональной.
5. Нахидом случайное число z.
6. Переходим в исходную систему координат z->y->x

В случае, если нужно сгенерировать много случайных чисел, то шаги 1-4 можно выполнить один раз.

Критическим здесь является являестя этап нахиждения собственных векторов. К сожелению, в boost.uBLAS, нет подходящей функции, но можно воспользоваться [eigen](http://yang.amp.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~yyama/computer/FAQ/eigen/eigensystem.html) или [MKL](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dsyevd_ex.c.htm). Кроме того, задача нахождения собственных векторов - очень трудоемкая (сложенее нахождения обратной матрицы), и в случае плохо обусловленных матриц большого размера, удовлетворительного алгоритма просто не сущесвует. Даже размерность 10 может оказаться критической, с точки зрения потери точности.